# Changing HttpListener idle HTTP connections timeout in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, timeout, httplistener

I have a project that uses .NET Framework 4.0.
It creates the instance of HttpListener that handles long-lasting HTTP requests that may be idle for a long time (30 minutes or longer).
I control both the server and the client.

Seems that HttpListener class has a timeout that causes the HTTP connection to close if there is no data sent for some time interval.
I need to increase that timeout value. What is the way to do it in .NET 4.0?

There is a TimeoutManager property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.timeoutmanager.aspx   which has the required “IdelConnection” setting, but it only appeared in 4.5